# Active noise cancellation technology measurements

Tags: acoustics

As you know the active noise cancellation technology used in many application such as protection of aircraft cabins and car interiors to reduce engine noise also some headphones use this feature to reduce unwanted ambient sounds.

Actually I don't know the details of how this feature works, but I do know that it has input (microphone) that receives noise waves, control unit that invert the incoming noise waves and output (speakers) to emit inverted noise waves and therefore they will cancel each other.

What I'm not understanding is that If we considered the sound waves are traveling in air, then the **inverted** noise waves emitted from the speaker will reach the listener before they combine with the original noise waves so they cancel each other while the **inverted** noise waves are traveling in a solid-media (components of the microphone, speaker, etc.) faster than the original noise waves traveling in air.

[image]

I'm I missing something or there is another feature they use to adjust the speed of sound in the active noise cancellation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum delay for effective active noise cancelling?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60614/)

Comment: Just put some delay into the control unit...

Comment: @DarioP Is that really gonna balance the delay? Or just make it more accurate?

Comment: @MohammadFakhrey One could put a second microphone on the inside of the headphone and actively tune the delay time to minimize the audible noise (though that may not be necessary in practice).

Comment: You could orient the electronics perpendicular to the incident sound wave's direction of propagation. Or at least on an angle. That way the speaker and microphone are closer together and a time delay isn't necessary. I'm confused why placing the speaker farther from the listener's ear wasn't considered?